# unable to send mail from a jsp webapp using java mail api

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail

I want to send a mail when the given jsp page is executed. I have included both the javamail jar file and java activation framework jar file. But this code is giving error that password is not specified, whereas I have provided the correct password as shown in the code below. Any help would be highly appreciated! Totally new to JSP.

```
   <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
   <%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
   <%@ page import = "javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
   <%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>

   <%
   String result;

   // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "xzu@gmail.com";

   // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
   String from = "xzu@gmail.com";

   // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
   String host = "localhost";

   // Get system properties object
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.user", "xzu@gmail.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.password", "xzu");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   try {
  // Create a default MimeMessage object.
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

  // Set From: header field of the header.
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

  // Set To: header field of the header.
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                           new InternetAddress(to));
  // Set Subject: header field
  message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

  // Now set the actual message
  message.setText("This is actual message");

  // Send message
  Transport.send(message);
  result = "Sent message successfully....";
  } catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
  result = mex.getMessage();
  }
  %>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Send Email using JSP</title>
  </head>

   <body>
  <center>
     <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
  </center>

  <p align = "center">
     <% 
        out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
     %>
  </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Check this out. It's all you need. http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/sending-e-mail-with-jsp-servlet-and-javamail

Comment: Fix these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and follow this [Gmail example](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail) in the JavaMail FAQ.  If it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you dont have a mail server running on your machine and you try to send email using google...

Then the host = localhost is wrong.

To do this you need something like:

```
final String username = "xyz@gmail.com";
final String password = "password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Then create a session

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
  });
```

And then send your email by:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(messageText);
Transport.send(message);
```